# MySQL table with identical name multiple times in same database

Tags: mysql, table, duplication

I stumbled into a pretty nasty bug into our PROD environment

I was running some alter scripts and it appears it ended up duplicating the table for each column altered.

I've tested with MySQL Workbench, HeidSQL and DBBeaver they all display same duplicated results.

Bear in mind below examples it's just one table, but I have this issue with 4 different tables in the same Database

[image: DBBeaver screenshot]

Any table that appears duplicated now it's also duplicated in the DB backup script.
If I click and drop one, all entries are gone.
When I run the create script, the table is multiplied for each column.

Per question below this the CREATE script, this script is multipled same in the dump script.
If I drop the table, all entries are gone. When run this script, they're all back

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employee`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employeeNumber` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `phoneNumber` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `merchantId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `departmentId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `startDate` date NOT NULL,
  `endDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `contract` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `countryId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `createdDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modifiedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `isActive` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `contractIssueDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `visaType` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visaStartDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `visaEndDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `knownAs` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateOfBirth` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ppsNumber` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `passOrIdNumber` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nokName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nokAddress` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nokRelationship` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nokPhoneNumber` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastModifiedUserId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `honorificTitleId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `genderId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_country_idx` (`countryId`),
  KEY `fk_department_idx` (`departmentId`),
  KEY `fk_gender_idx` (`genderId`),
  KEY `fk_honorificTitle_idx` (`honorificTitleId`),
  KEY `fk_merchant_idx` (`merchantId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_country` FOREIGN KEY (`countryId`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dep` FOREIGN KEY (`departmentId`) REFERENCES `department` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_gender` FOREIGN KEY (`genderId`) REFERENCES `gender` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_honorificTitle` FOREIGN KEY (`honorificTitleId`) REFERENCES `honorificTitle` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_merchant2` FOREIGN KEY (`merchantId`) REFERENCES `merchant` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated on how to prevent or resolve it.

Thank you

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Could you provide the script that you ran that resulted in this occurring? It **looks** to me that some sort of corruption is going on - there is no way that you should be able to have two objects with the same name and type in the same schema! I'd be looking at a complete reinstall from bare metal up OS and db - just IMHO.

Comment: Also, can you see the same thing using the `mysql` CLI tool?

Comment: Your script looks like a perfectly normal `CREATE TABLE...` script which should create one and **only** one table. I've **never** seen this occur before and the only explantion that I can offer is the one above about some sort of corruption. Do you see anything unusual in any of the logs?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary in logs that I can see. It certainly looks like some sort of corruption. The system still works correctly and am able to retrieve the data from the table.

Comment: Check with `select table_schema, table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables where table_name = 'employee'`. Note that since you quoted the name, you may have to do that in your query as well (dependent of how your DBMS store identifiers)

Comment: Tried that also Describe only returns one result, however any GUI i've tried displays multi e versions of the tables

Comment: Go into the file system, look in the directory with the name of the database, see what you find.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: MySQL 5.7, Don't have access to the file system it's an Azure Cloud MySQL DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem through Azure Helpdesk

The problem was that the parameter `dir_cache_fine_grained_enabled` switched on during an Azure update.
This needed to be switched off and the DB server restarted. After restart things went back to normal

The parameter is not available to the public.